# How do I use a shared dynamic library in c++ project?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

I am running 64bit Linux and using Netbeans 8.0 IDE. I simply created new C++ project, so far only containing some HelloWorld code. I want to use a third party library for logging. I chose log4cpp (since I have experience with Java and it is supposed to have similar interface).

I installed liblog4cpp from the repositories, and can see it in /usr/lib, to be clear:

```
$ locate log4cpp
/usr/lib/liblog4cpp.so
/usr/lib/liblog4cpp.so.5
/usr/lib/liblog4cpp.so.5.0.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cpp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cpp.so.5
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cpp5
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cpp5/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cpp5/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cpp5/README
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cpp5/THANKS
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cpp5/TODO
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cpp5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cpp5/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cpp5/copyright
/var/cache/apt/archives/liblog4cpp5_1.0-4_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cpp5.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cpp5.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cpp5.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cpp5.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cpp5.shlibs
```

I am having big trouble on how to #include it in my application. Inspired by example from the documentation I put in my source:

```
#include "log4cpp/Category.hh"
#include "log4cpp/Appender.hh"
#include "log4cpp/FileAppender.hh"
#include "log4cpp/OstreamAppender.hh"
#include "log4cpp/Layout.hh"
#include "log4cpp/BasicLayout.hh"
#include "log4cpp/Priority.hh"
```

I was first using Makefile generated by netbeans, however could not figure out how to configure the project to make it work. All my trials lead to the following error (line 16 being the first #include):

```
$ make
src/main.cpp:16:31: fatal error: log4cpp/Category.hh: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/NetworkConfiguration.o] Error 1
```

I also tried a custom Makefile, giving g++ argument -llog4cpp, but I always get the same error. I can provide more info/code if it will be helpful. The solution does not need to depend on the IDE, I feel like I just misunderstood how linking works, so feel free to educate me on how to achieve what I want from console with custom Makefile for example.

Comment: This might be you didn't have added include directory of `logcpp` to project include path.

Comment: Did you install liblog4cpp or liblog4cpp-dev?  The difference is that the first package only contains the libraries.  The second is the development kit which includes the headers.

Comment: If you installed the -dev version, the headers should be in /usr/include

Comment: That makes sense cup. Installing the dev package resolves the issue. Thanks, if you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since cup still has not posted an answer, I am paraphrasing his comment as an accepted answer.

Install liblog4cpp-dev. The difference is that liblog4cpp only contains the libraries while liblog4cpp-dev is the development kit which includes the headers.